# Nexus sonatype does not get zip dependency

Tags: maven, nexus

I have setup Sonatype Nexus with Maven and seems to be working. However, my project depends (transitively) on [docbook-xsl-1.75.2](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/docbook/docbook-xsl/1.75.2/) but instead of a jar there you find a zip file. Is this the reason why Nexus is not getting it, that it is a zip file? I haven't found any Nexus configuration page in the web console offering a possible filter.

I browse my Nexus repository and see it gets the pom file but nothing else.

Comment: Try using the `generate-resources` goal to retrieve the content of this dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next day, and after restarting Nexus it pulled the dependency. I don't still understand the magic behind Nexus not seeing the dependencies while they are clearly available but at least this question is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

That module has no main artifact, it's packaging type is set to "pom".

What it does have is two additional artifacts which can be retrieved using Maven module classifiers as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.docbook</groupId>
  <artifactId>docbook-xsl</artifactId>
  <version>1.75.2</version>
  <classifier>resources</classifier>
  <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

And

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.docbook</groupId>
  <artifactId>docbook-xsl</artifactId>
  <version>1.75.2</version>
  <classifier>ns-resources</classifier>
  <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

Sorry, I have no idea how you'd retrieve these as transitive dependencies.